# Live Server (VsCode) открывает страницы, но не обновляет их

Tags: сервер, live

Live Server перестал обновлять страницы после изменений. Автосохранение страниц активно. Попытка удалить  и переустановить ничего не дала. Возможно кто-то знает в чем причина или может посоветовать похожие расширения, без установок Gulp и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Live Server перестал обновлять страницы.

**Примечание: все операции желательно выполнять перезапуская стр. Live Server.
Дефолтно остановив ALT+L ALT+C и запустив ALT+LALT+O**

1. Отключите все программы типа месенджеров, которые могут забивать порты. (проверить перезагрузив)
2. Изменить рабочую область. Ctrl + Shift + P > Live Server: Change Live Srever Workspace > ‘указать свою’ (проверить перезагрузив)
3. Заходим в шестерёнку > настройки (CTRL + ,). В верхнем углу ищем листочек с завёрнутым уголком и стрелочкой, это файл .json Открываем его, делаем бекап содержимого, после если есть то удаляем все строки с liveServer (проверить перезагрузив)
4. Идём в расширения CTRL+SHIFT+X ищем live Server жмём шестерёнку > Параметры расширения. У вас может быть тут что то сбилось или отключилось. Если нажать на один из пунктов, слева от него появится шестерёнка с доп.функциями.
   [image: скриншот шестерёнки]

В моём случае в доп.функциях я сбросил параметры Live Server Settings: Proxy и мне помогло, не факт что поможет в вашем случае.
Перечислил все баги и их решения, что знал на сегодня.

Answer (score -1):

Если папка с проектом начинается на `#`, то `live server` не обновляет страницу.

Comment: Можете ли вы, пожалуйста, дополнить ответ деталями, нажав кнопку [edit]?